# Passing string to function as an object's property in "let" gives "Unexpected token }"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a 'generic' charting function which takes a series of parameters for charting different data values with different labels and baseline values. I've created the following function to handle this:

```
function ProcessChart(obj, valToChart, desc, element, baselineVal) {
    let arr = obj.map(e => {
        let { dateTime, [valToChart] } = e; // ERROR: Unexpected token }
        return [new Date(dateTime), +[valToChart]];
    });

    arr.unshift(["DateTime", desc]);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr)

    var options = {
        title: desc + " for " + obj[0].computerName,
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        animation: {
            startup: false,
            duration: 500
        },
        vAxis: {
            baseline: baselineVal,
            baselineColor: 'red'
        }
    };

    var chart = new 
    google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(element));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**Caller:**

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(ProcessChart(obj, "averageJitterInMs", "Average Jitter (ms)", "line-jitter-8hr", 10))
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(ProcessChart(obj, "roundTripLatencyInMs", 'Round-Trip Latency (ms)', 'line-delay-8-hr', 8))
```

The problem is my `valToChart` being passed gives an error:

> Unexpected token }

Is there another way I should be expressing this as a dynamic property on my `obj` object? I've tested this code with 'hard-coded' values in each place and it works fine.

Comment: `let { dateTime, [valToChart] } = e` When destructuring an object, if you aren't extracting the property immediately into a variable (like with `dateTime`), you need to list the property name.

Comment: oh, so you're expecting `let { dateTime, [valToChart] } = e;` to result in two variables, `dateTime`, and `averageJitterInMs` or `roundTripLatencyInMs` - destructuring doesn't work that way

Comment: `let { dateTime } = e, prop = e[valToChart]; return [new Date(dateTime), +prop];` - although, you may as well just `let arr = obj.map(e => [new Date(e.dateTime), +e[valToChart]]);`

Comment: @JaromandaX there are two objects in the array, a DateTime value and an integer. The source `obj` has a whole series of key/value pairs which I'll use to draw different charts on the page. I'm copying 95% of the code for each chart if I can't pass parameters. So a correction on your suggestion, dateTime is just a Date. The `[valToChart]` is dynamic (based on the caller passing it the object's property name).

Comment: Yes. I know all that. You don't see the difference between . notation and []. It never looks for e.valToChart

Comment: Try my answer. You'll see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No destructuring required (it doesn't work that way anyway)

```
let arr = obj.map(e => [new Date(e.dateTime), +e[valToChart]]);
```

Should do what you want

Comment: Wow, you ARE a god! ;-)

Comment: Once was, not any more :p

Comment: Clarifying question...if I wanted the chart type to be dynamic as well using `var chart = new google.visualization.[chartType](document.getElementById(elementId));` as an example, I'm struggling to understand how this one could be done since I'm not using a map.

Comment: use either `.` OR `[]` ... is `chartType` a string variable? `google.visualization[chartType](document.getElementById(elementId));`

Comment: Here are the calling bits: `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(ProcessChart(obj, "LineChart", "averageJitterInMs", "Average Jitter (ms)", "line-jitter-8hr", 10))`. This was the original charting object: `var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(elementId));`

Comment: `google.visualization[chartType](document.getElementById(elementId));` should be right then

Comment: Right again. If you know of any good docs on this matter I'd appreciate reading up on it.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) has good docs for JS in general - I can't find the docs for this though